# Changing the value of a binding in a function's lexical environment

Tags: javascript, theory

When a function is invoked, a new lexical environment is created for that invocation. That lexical environment contains an environment record, which in turn holds the local named bindings which exist in that environment. So, for instance:

```
(function () {

    var x = 123;

    // other code

}());
```

In the above function invocation, there will exist a binding with the name `"x"` and the value `123`, in the function's lexical environment.

Now, if we wanted to change the value of that binding, we could:

1. set the identifier `x` as the left-hand side of one of the assignment operators:

   ```
   x = 456; 
   // the value of the "x" binding has changed to 456
   ```
2. set the identifier `x` as the operand of a prefix/suffix increment/decrement operator:

   ```
   x++;
   // the value of the "x" binding has changed to 124
   ```

**My question:** Are those the only two methods to change the value of the "x" binding?

Comment: `x++;` is just a syntactic shortcut for `x = x + 1;` so you really have only one assignment type described here.

Comment: Isn't "assignment" the usual term, instead of "binding" ?

Comment: @dystroy http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.5

Comment: @dystroy Assignment works with expressions. One expression is assigned to another expression. On the other hand, a name is bound to an lexical environment. Those are just two different matters.

Comment: @dystroy `++`/`--`, and `=` are two *different* operators which both happen to invoke the internal `PutValue` method which in turn changes the value of the binding. Just because one operator can be expressed via a combination of other operators, does not make it less significant. Note that the `=` operator does *not* own the `PutValue` internal method. It is just invoking it internally. Just like the `++` is. Both operators are equal here, and should both be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think we should talk about 'bindings' here. The link @Incognito gave in comments to the question describes binding of variables and functions - but not their *values*.

As 'x' in your example has a primitive value assigned, I don't think there's a way to alter it - if not in an assignment (direct or syntax-sugar one).

For example, this...

```
var x = 42;
x.y   = 24;
```

... won't actually result in changing `x` (it gets converted into an object, assigned a new property, but then this object will be just thrown away).

And this...

```
function x() { ... }
```

... will also fail to assign a new value to `x`.

UPDATE: My point is that `'var x = 42'` statement in JS (but not in Erlang) won't result in binding of `42` (number literal) to variable `x`.

Comment: 262-5 uses "binding" 191 times. I don't see the problem with it, as it's not interchangeable with assignment.

Comment: I'm not using "binding" as an synonym for "assignment". Bindings exist in lexical environments, whereas assignments occur in code. Those two terms describe different matters.

Comment: Regarding your update: Again, I'm not using the term "binding" as an synonym for "assignment". So, the value `42` is **assigned** to the variable `x`. As a result, the value of the **binding** `"x"` in the function's lexical environment is changed to `42`.

Comment: Just to clarify, your answer is that besides via the assignment, and increment/decrement operators (as mentioned in my question), it is *not* possible to change the value of the `"x"` binding in the function's lexical environment, correct?

Comment: Correct. Even this `x.something` I've talked about won't change the literal value of `x` binding, it will still refer to the same object.